# IEEE Style for Number Array

Tags: publications, mathematics, writing-style, formatting, ieee

What is the IEEE preferred style for writing a number array with a specific step size? There seem to be several options:

```
1: (start, step, stop)

2: (start:step:stop)

3: start ... (step) ... stop
```

There are a few other (seemingly) equally valid representations, even ignoring the differentiation between inclusive and exclusive brackets. I say start/stop instead of min/max because at least one of my arrays has a negative step size, that is, the numbers are getting smaller.

Is there a prefered style or is it just whatever floats my boat? I can't find any suggestions in the [IEEE Style Manual](http://www.ieee.org/documents/style_manual.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEEE doesn't care: use whatever best communicates to your readers, and *make sure you explain it* if you aren't using a blatantly obvious notation.

Comment: Alright, so no official weigh in, what do you reckon "blatantly obvious notation" is then?

Comment: The only thing I would consider obvious is in the middle of an actual code sample from a well known language, e.g., MATLAB. Otherwise, spend the short sentence to explain your notation